# Send Parent View to a child (BottomSheetDialogFragment)

Tags: kotlin, bottom-sheet, android-bottomsheetdialog, bottomsheetdialogfragment

today I'm wondering if it's possible to do this. I mean, when I load a child view send the parent view. In another words I want to handle the parent when I'm on the child.

Parent View

```
  imgFilter.setOnClickListener {
            MyDialogFragment().show(requireActivity().supportFragmentManager,"filter_dialog")
        }
```

Child View

```
class MyDialogFragment : BottomSheetDialogFragment() {
    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
    val dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState) as BottomSheetDialog

    val view = View.inflate(context, R.layout.filter_sheet_layout, null)

    val linearLayout = view.findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.root)
    val params = linearLayout.layoutParams as LinearLayout.LayoutParams
    params.height = getScreenHeight()
    linearLayout.layoutParams = params

    backArrowClick(view)
    hideKeyboard()


    dialog.setContentView(view)
    mBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(view.parent as View)

    parentFragment?.view?.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.name_store)?.text = "Hello World"

    return dialog
}
}
```

I don't if it's possible to do or If you have another suggestion I'm here to hear and learn.

Thank you so much!

Comment: `parentFragment?.view` is that what you need?

Comment: parentFragment = null 

:c

Comment: Try with `MyDialogFragment().show(childFragmentManager, "filter_dialog")`

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH YOU MADE MY DAY

Comment: Care to give back the favor with an upvote on the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `show` method is receiving as an argument the fragment manager from the activity so it can't find the parent fragment

```
MyDialogFragment().show(childFragmentManager, "filter_dialog")
```

Should allow to `parentFragment?.view?` to be found.